# Deserializing axios response data to a class instance

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs, deserialization

1. I am hitting an external API using axios (NestJs app).
2. I specify the response type (lets say `ResponseDto`)
3. When I get the data from axios (response.data), it is a simple plain JS object. As a result I cannot use any functions I defined in the `ResponseDto` class. So I get error `TypeError: response.data.isValid is not a function`.

Response Class:

```
import { InfoDto } from './info.dto';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class ResponseDto {
  @Type(() => InfoDto)
  private infos: InfoDto[];

  isValid(): boolean {
    return this.infos.length > 0;
  }
}
```

Info DTO

```
export class InfoDto {
  private readonly message: string;

  isMessageEmpty(): boolean {
    return !this.message;
  }
}
```

Api Call

```
this.httpService.axiosRef
.post<ResponseDto>(apiUrl, request, {
  headers: headers,
})
.then((response) => response.data);
```

I expect response.data to be of type ResponseDto but it is an Object.
What I get

```
Object {
         "infos": Array(1)[
           Object {
             "message": "message"
           }
         ]
       }
```

What I want

```
ResponseDto {
         "infos": Array(1)[
           InfoDto {
             "message": "message"
           }
         ]
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use something like `class-transformer` to take the JSON object into a class instance, or manually do that yourself via instantiating a new class and assigning the properties.

```js
this.httpService.axiosRef
.post<ResponseDto>(apiUrl, request, {
  headers: headers,
})
.then((response) => response.data)
.then((data) => plainToInstance(ResponseDto, data))
.then((instance) => {
  if (!instance.isValid) {
    throw new Error('Invalid data from third party API);
  }
  return instance;
});
```

These can also be combined to the same `then`, just wanted to separate them out for the purpose of example.